# Internet Wifi 100 half duplex?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Well I have been trying to figure out why the fios connection
has been total crap on wifi. I was looking through some
settings and found the port configuration option somewhere in
the settings where it is only set on 10 half duplex.

When I change the setting to 100 half or 1000 half
IT JUST WON'T CHANGE!

I have this router 
[image]
http://www.actiontec.com/products/datasheets/VrznMI424WRrevI_dtsht_Verzn%20brnded.pdf

Anyone have an idea on why and how to solve this?
(I am no expert but is it because the power supply limiting it?)
Wired connections can be set to 1000 full-duplex and the setting updates just fine.

Any information would be helpful on what I have to change or buy.

[image]

Comment: Did you try 100 full duplex?

Comment: 10/100/1000 = ethernet cabling, not wifi... and all wireless is half duplex just that they use different frequency and overlap. My understanding that is......

Comment: You say you "found the port configuration option somewhere in the settings". The port configuration for what port?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz port congrif for the 5 output ports, Wan / lan1/lan2/lan3/lan4

Comment: @cybernard wireless uses halfdup and i have ofc tried all the settings it just won't change.

Comment: @logman i think wifi also has this setting.. why else would it show this setting and let you pick which one you want?

Comment: @victor post a screen shot of the settings. Connection is defined in wifi as 802.11 a/b/g/n etc... from the pdf link in your post your Wireless support b/g/n. Interfaces are LAN/WAN (10/100/1000BaseT Ethernet) which are wires not wireless.

Comment: @victor: You're saying all five output ports are showing 100/half? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @logman http://i152.photobucket.com/albums/s161/aznvicO/1_zps66d8f1d2.jpg?t=1374020370

Comment: @DavidSchwartz screen shot above

Comment: The picture from the photobucket display only wired connections. There is nothing there related to wireless/wifi. I added the image to the question.

Comment: your WAN port is only 10 half duplex. That a huge bottle neck going out to the internet. Check your connections and cables, get your isp to send a tech to check it. What is your current internet speed suppose to be speedwise?

Comment: well it is fios.. but a speed test via wifi is not even better than a dsl connection with HIGH ping spikes. connection on speed test.net is B-

Comment: half-duplex means you can only communicate in one direction at one time. Think "walkie talkie" when its half-duplex. "Transmission of data in just one direction at a time". High Spikes is because of the half duplex. The speed test has to transmit data and then STOP to retrieve a little bit a data from the other end and then continue sending again.... Over and Over.... Full Duplex will allow transmitting data both ways at the same time. Your speed will increase dramatically even if its Fios. Half duplex is usually caused now a days from bad cables or connections.

Comment: Your LAN ports should be able to get 1000 if you use the correct cables, the connections are good and your ethernet adapters support 1000 (older network adapters do not).